# How to add file upload button to the microsoft teams bot framework?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

current situation:
Upload is possible on mobile, but not on pc app

I found below but I don't know where is the `manifest(schema) file` and how to apply them for my bot.
I can not find `supportsFiles` configurations.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/bots-filesv4#configure-the-bot-to-support-files

thanks